# Jmeter http request completion notification

Tags: performance, jmeter, sequential

Is their a way in Jmeter to control sending of HTTP request? My scenario is like

1. send Request 1
2. receive response 1
3. send Request 2
4. receive response 2

Note: the requests are sent one by one as an when response is received. Flooding the server with parallel request ( by setting no of thread > 1) will yield wrong response. So I want that Request 2 is to be triggered  after receiving response 1.

The bad solution that works is:

- send Request 1
- sleep 2 second
- receive response 1
- send Request 2
- sleep 2 second
- receive response 2

More precisely the requirement is "read values stored in a csv file one by one and send http post request". The sequence what I wanted to achieve is Send_1, Receive_1, Send_2, Receive_2.......Send_n, Receive_n". My thread group setting is

`Number of threads =1 Ramp up period =1 Loop Count = 10 ( as I want to read 10 values from csv and send out)`

What I observed is Send_1, Send_2, ..Send_10 are sent immediately without giving server enough time to respond. How should I configure this so that Send and Receive will progress in locked step manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything, by default JMeter waits for response for the previous Sampler before starting next one (assuming that you're using "normal" [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler), if you're getting errors with your setup without "sleep" time - it indicates the issue with your application, not with JMeter.

If you need the evidence you can

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) with the following code:

   ```
   log.info(' Iteration: ' + vars.getIteration() +  '; Sampler ' + sampler.getName() + ' started')
   ```
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with the following code:

   ```
   log.info(' Iteration: ' + vars.getIteration() +  '; Sampler ' + sampler.getName() + ' ended')
   ```

where:

- `sampler.getName()` returns current Sampler label
- `vars.getIteration()` returns current loop of the Thread Group

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details if needed.

This way you will get sampler start and end time into [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging):

[image]

As you can see there are several milliseconds between ending the `Sampler 1` and starting the `Sampler 2` so you don't need to introduce any explicit waits.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter has this behaviour by default, e.g. each Thread within a Thread Group will wait for the response to a request before sending the next request in your test plan.

When you do want multiple requests hitting your service concurrently you achieve this by altering the number of Threads in your Thread Group.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer):

> The purpose of the SyncTimer is to block threads until X number of threads have been blocked, and then they are all released at once

> Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by

> Number of threads to release at once. Setting it to 0 is equivalent to setting it to Number of threads in Thread Group.